# Implementation of Review method in Facebook Application

Tags: facebook

I have seen one application in which there was a button of write a review. 
Clicking on it opens an editor on the same page with options Rating and comments.

I want to know whether there is an api for the same as i want to implement it in my application.

This is the applictaion in which it is implemented:

http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=101539264719#/cafeworld?v=app_6261817190

Please help me

Thanks

Pankaj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have posted the same issue in facebook developer forum.
Someone in the forum told me that there is a regular review tab.
Every application profile page has it.
I checked the same on my application profile page and found out that there is a review tab for my application.

You can check the post at following link:

http://forum.developers.facebook.com/viewtopic.php?id=42901

Regards,

Pankaj